# Remove from string what does not match a JSON pattern

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm currently trying to remove from a string what does not a regex pattern. I have a string, and I'm trying to parse out the JSON from it. Here is an example.

I would like to remove everything from the string that doesn't match the following
regex pattern `JSON_FORMAT = /\{.*\:\{.*\:.*\}\}/`. I try using `text.gsub(JSON_FORMAT, '')` but that just ended up removing what match. Which is the opposite of what im looking for.

Comment: Looks like you need `text.scan(JSON_FORMAT).join(" ")`

Comment: Or if you expect not more than one match `text[JSON_FORMAT]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming string object is what you pasted as input text in your rubular link, the json is just everything between each open and closing curly brace `{}` so the regex is very simple.

```
require 'json' # require the standard lib

str = # the string in your rubular example

regex = /\{.*\}/
array = str.scan(regex).map{|j| JSON.parse(j.gsub(/\\/,''))}

# array is now a collection of ruby hashes.
# if you need them converted to a single json object you can do
json = array.to_json
```

The ruby [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/String.html#method-i-scan) method does most of what you need.  But you will need to remove the double escape characters which is what is done inside the `.map` here using the [JSON stdlib](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html)